# ssis upserting 10^8 rows - process by batch?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008, large-data

I have to gather a large volume of data from various SQL Server tables (~around 300 million rows) and to upsert them into a single fact table in my data warehouse.

1/ **What is the best strategy to import all these rows?**

2/ **Is this a good practice to import by batches**? How big should be a batch? 10k rows is ok?

Comment: My plan to perform this import like this:

**1/** Add a new column in each source table, called *ImportedDate* as *DATETIME2 NOT NULL* </pre>
**2/** Create a loop container where read the first 10k rows WHERE ImportedDate IS NOT NULL
**3/** Decide to perform update (via Ole DB command) or insert row in destination via a Lookup task
**4/** Update *ImportedDate* column for the processed rows in the destination table.

Comment: For your updates I select you drop all the updates in a staging table and perform a single UPDATE from that. You'll be waiting forever for the SSIS updates to finish.

Comment: @ElectricLlama: you mean to import all data in a staging table and then to process them in batches and then to delete processed rows from staging tables?

Comment: Possibly. The main point is do not use SSIS update as it's slow. How often do you need to do this, is it a one off?

Comment: @ElectricLlama: one time as we're talking about the initial load.

Comment: If this is a one time thing, then there are various ways of achieving it. I have worked on a similar situation but with about 60 million records at a time using SSIS and stored proc.

Comment: Agree with @rvphx. It also depends on your environment. Anyway .. use SSIS to import individual tables from source database to individual staging tables in destination database. Stored procedure to process and save into Fact table. If you need to reload the Fact table, truncate the Staging and Fact table to reload. In SSIS use Data Flow Task to import tables and Execute SQL Task object to start stored procedure. Another option if you have space to restore the source database into the data warehouse SQL Server instance and process using SQL script or stored procedure

Comment: Are the source tables on the same or different servers? How many tables/server involved?

Comment: @ElectricLlama: all source tables are on the same server (which is different than the destination server). We're talking about 8 tables, all off them multiplied on 7 databases (one for different client).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I designed this was for a data movement between 3 different layers

1. Landing Area
2. Staging area (where most of the look ups and key substitutions happened)
3. Data Warehouse

We created bulk tables in the landing area without any sort of key's or anything on there. We would simply land the data in that area and then would move it further along the system.

The way I designed the package was to create 2 very simple table in SQL Server with 4 columns each. The first table, I called it ToBeProcessed and the 2nd (quite obviously) Processed.
The columns that I had were

1)

```
dbo.ToBeProcessed

(ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),

BeginDate DATETIME,
EndDate DateTime,
Processed VARCHAR(1)

)
```

2)

```
 dbo.Processed

( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
ProcessedEndDate DATETIME,
TableName VARCHAR (24),
CompletedDateTime DATETIME
)
```

What I did was to populate the ToBeProcessed Table with date ranges spanning a week each. For example 1st Row would be from 01/01/2014 to 01/07/2014, the next row would be from 01/08/2014 to 01/15/2014 and so on. This makes sure that you dont overlap any piece of data that you are pulling in.

**On the SSIS Side** you would want to create a for each loop container and parse through all the dates in the 1st table one by one. You can parametrize your Data Flow task with the variables you would create to store the dates from the For each loop container. Every time a weeks worth of data gets processed, you simple insert the end date into your 2nd table.

This makes sure that you have a track of the data you have processed. The reason for doing this is because if the package fails for any reason, you can start from the point of failure without repulling all the data that you have already processed (I think in your case, you may want to turn the T-Logs off if you are not working on production environment).

As for upserting, I think using a merge statement could be an option, but it all depends on what your processing time frames are. If you are looking to turn this around over the weekend, I would suggest using a stored proc on the data set and making sure that your Log tables can grow comfortably with that amount of data.

This is a brief summary of the quick and dirty way which worked for me. This does not mean its the best method out there, but certainly got the job done for me. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I like your approach! Why did you need to have the landing area and staging area in the same time?

Comment: We had to keep the bulk tables(historical data) separate from the daily ETL tables. We created the landing area so that we could have a backup of the historical data should we need to recalculate something in the event of a number not making any sense. The Staging area was more of the final DB where all things either cleared up (in terms of look ups and stuff) or be rejected.